# Can't access a customProvider from another app. It says it's missing permissions it already has

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to make an app that access a SQLite table from another app with a custom content provider. I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.example.carlos.gymlog.MiContentProvider uri content://mi.uri.porquesi/sesiones from pid=2375, uid=10064 requires android.permission.permRead, or grantUriPermission()
```

However, my "sender" app (the one with the database) already has the required permissions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.carlos.gymlog" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MiTema" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Principal"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:name="MiContentProvider"
            android:authorities="mi.uri.porquesi"
            android:readPermission="android.permission.permRead"
            android:exported="true"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"> </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the code that causes the error in the "receiver" app (the one that tries to access the other):

```
ArrayList<Sesion> sacarDatos(Context c){

        Uri cUri = Uri.parse("content://mi.uri.porquesi/sesiones");
        ContentProviderClient miCP = c.getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient(cUri);

        ArrayList<Sesion> sesiones = null;
        try {
            Cursor cur  = miCP.query(cUri, null, null, null, null);
            sesiones = new ArrayList<Sesion>();
            cur.moveToFirst();
            Sesion sesion = null;
            do {
                sesion = new Sesion(cur.getInt(0),cur.getInt(1),cur.getInt(2),cur.getInt(3));
                sesiones.add(sesion);
            } while (cur.moveToNext());

        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sesiones;
    }
```

And lastly, this is my custom content provider:

```
public class MiContentProvider extends android.content.ContentProvider {

    private static final String uri = "content://mi.uri.porquesi";

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(uri);


    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

        BaseDatosHelper miBD = new BaseDatosHelper(getContext(), "SESIONES", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = miBD.getWritableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb  = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        qb.setTables("SESIONES");

        Cursor cur = qb.query(db,projection,selection,selectionArgs,"","",sortOrder);
        cur.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(),uri);
        return cur;
    }
```

(the rest of the methods like insert() aren't implemented, they just return null or whatever it is, I just want to select data not insert it).

EDIT:

My app A has

```
 <provider android:name="MiContentProvider"
        android:authorities="mi.uri.porquesi"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="mi.permision"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"> </provider>
    <permission
        android:name="mi.permision"
        />
```

( just a random temporal name)

In app B, I've included

```
<uses-permission android:name="mi.permision"/>
```

However, now I get:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.example.carlos.gymlog.MiContentProvider from ProcessRecord{335efe6e 3116:com.example.carlos.sample/u0a67} (pid=3116, uid=10067) requires mi.permision or mi.permision
```

So it recognizes that I need my custom permission, but it doesn't recognize that my app B is using it. Why??

Comment: "However, my "sender" app (the one with the database) already has the required permissions" -- that is the manifest of the app with the `ContentProvider`. It is not the manifest of the app that is trying to talk to the `ContentProvider`. Not only does that app need to have a `<uses-permission>` element, but it needs to be installed after the app that has the corresponding `<permission>` element. And, [there are security issues with custom permissions](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/PERMS.md).

Comment: @CommonsWare ok, so how should I include that permission in the reader app's manifest? <uses-permission> referencing which permission inside?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say that we have App A and App B. App A has the `ContentProvider`; App B wants to use the `ContentProvider` from App A. And, you want to defend the `ContentProvider`, with a custom permission.

App A needs [a `<permission>` element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html) in its manifest, with your custom permission name in the `android:name` attribute. **DO NOT** use an `android.permission` prefix on that custom permission name, as you are not a developer on the Android Open Source Project. Use something namespaced for your app, such as `com.kace91.permission.AND_REMEMBER_THAT_CUSTOM_PERMISSIONS_HAVE_SECURITY_ISSUES`.

App A then needs an attribute, on [the `<provider>` manifest element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html), that has a value matching the name of the `android:name` attribute of the `<permission>` element. Either use `android:permission` to defend all operations, or have *two* custom permissions and use `android:readPermission` and `android:writePermission`. **DO NOT** simply use `android:readPermission`, as that means that any app can modify the `ContentProvider` without permission, and it is rather unlikely that this is what the user wants.

App A also needs an `android:exported="true"` attribute on the `<provider>` element, to say that third party apps can initiate communications with that `ContentProvider`.

App B can then have [a `<uses-permission>` manifest element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html), with an `android:name` attribute value matching the `android:name` attribute of the `<permission>` element from App A. If you used two permissions, for read and write, App B would need two `<uses-permission>` elements.

Then, if App A is installed before App B, and the user agrees to grant App B permission to hold the custom permission, App B will be able to perform the designated operations on App A's `ContentProvider`.

And, as noted in my comment, [there are security issues with custom permissions](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/PERMS.md).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've done everything you said, however my app doesn't recognize that I have the custom permission. Please see my update to the original thread for details.

Comment: @kace91: Perhaps you have your `<permission>` and `<uses-permission>` elements in the wrong place in the manifest. They need to immediate children of `<manifest>`, peers of `<application>`. Also, you may need to uninstall and reinstall both apps to get the permissions to line up properly.

Comment: That was it! I had the elements as children of application. Thanks!